# Spring-Boot:How to get all request body in WebRequest

Tags: spring-boot, controller-advice

Is it possible to fetch RequestBody from WebRequest object?
I am handling exceptions from controller advice so would like to handle the request as well to send data back in response. I saw its documentation what I understood is we can fetch query params from that object for GET request. If there is any other approach which I missed can somebody please help.

```
@NonNull
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(
  @Nullable HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,
  @Nullable HttpHeaders headers,
  HttpStatus status,
  @Nullable WebRequest request) {
 //handling of input request we got from Spring Controller
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `InputStream / Reader` for access to the request's content. This will be the raw InputStream/Reader as exposed by the Servlet API. and/or response objects (typically from the Servlet API) as per official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html).

```
@NonNull
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(
  @Nullable HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,
  @Nullable HttpHeaders headers,
  HttpStatus status,
  @Nullable WebRequest request,
  InputStream requestContent
) {
 //handling of input request we got from Spring Controller
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When exception occurs in your controller - catch it and extract any and all info you want. Create your own class - Lets say `CustomErrorInfo` and fill it with all the info you want and throw your own custom exception that will contain your `CustomErrorInfo` class and the original exception. Than in your controller advice add method that would handle your custom exception and there you will have an access to your `CustomErrorInfo` class instance thast you filled when exception occurred